# Creating a lambda function as an event handler for an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, serverless-framework

I'm trying to do something pretty simple. I want to create a lambda function, an S3 bucket, and make the lambda function the event handler for the S3 bucket, using the serverless framework. Here's my definition file:

```
service:                      test-project

provider:
  name:                       aws
  stage:                      ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  runtime:                    nodejs8.10
  endpointType:               REGIONAL
  role:                       arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/lambda_role

functions:
  MyEventHandler:
    name:                     fn
    handler:                  src/fn.handler
    events:
      - s3: container

resources:
  Resources:
    S3BucketContainer:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: the-container-bucket
```

But when I run:

```
$ sls deploy  --region us-east-1  --stage dev
```

I get:

```
Serverless: Operation failed!

  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

  An error occurred: S3BucketContainer - Unable to validate the following destination configurations (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument; Request ID: xxxxx; S3 Extended Request ID: xxxxx).

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com

  Your Environment Information -----------------------------
     OS:                     linux
     Node Version:           8.10.0
     Serverless Version:     1.34.1
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: whats the policy that you have on the iam role you configured?

Comment: If you are referring to the `lambda_role` role, let me put it this way. I can specify a lambda function as an S3 event handler with the exact same role. That cannot be the problem. That role is evaluated when the lambda function is executed and not at the deployment time. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is horrible but right.

The bucket is trying to be created with config to send notifications to your lambda. At this point in the deployment, the lambda hasn't given the bucket permissions to invoke and so the bucket creation fails.

If you didn't specify a custom bucket resource (to change the bucket name), [serverless would have added the dependency automatically](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/master/lib/plugins/aws/package/compile/events/s3/index.js#L143).

That all said you're not the first and the [docs have been updated](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/pull/3921) to reflect this issue.

Add this additional resource and apparently (see below) it should work:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    MyEventHandlerLambdaPermissionContainerS3:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
      Properties:
        FunctionName:
          "Fn::GetAtt":
            - MyEventHandlerLambda
            - Arn
        Principal: "s3.amazonaws.com"
        Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
        SourceAccount:
          Ref: AWS::AccountId
        SourceArn: "arn:aws:s3:::the-container-bucket"
```

I say apparently because I resolved this differently ([see here](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3038#issuecomment-304804402)), using `DependsOn` to control the order in CloudFormation.